# JPA with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm a newbie with Java and I need to create a console application that is going to connect with 4 databases (access, vfp, mysql and sqlserver).

I started with hibernate.cfg.xml files and managed to configure them, one for each database. Then I realized that jpa was a better solution. So I changed all my hibernate files to a persistence.xml file with 4 persistence-unit.

The databases are working well, but to use them I have to create a lot of code. This is an example:

```
EntityManagerFactory dbPersistence = 
   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("oneOfMyDatabases");

EntityManager em = dbPersistence.createEntityManager();

Query query = em.createQuery("from ProductEntity").setMaxResults(10);

for (Object o : query.getResultList()) {
    ProductEntity c = (ProductEntity) o;
    System.out.println("Product " + c.getName());
}

cgPersistence.close();
```

I need to update one of the databases with data from the other databases.

It's a pain to create all the code like this, so I was thinking about creating repositories but I can't see how to create them with different entityManagers for each database.

I tried to inject the managers with google guice without success, but I couldn't handle how to close or where to close the persistence connection.

Finally, I've found Spring Data and it seems to be what I need, but I don't really understand how to use it.

I need some guide to get it working because I've read tons of tutorials and each of them appear to be different:
· Can I use the same persistence.xml or do I need another configuration file? I've seen that Spring Data has jpa compatibility but I'm not sure how it works.
· Is Spring Context the IOC Container of Spring Framework? Do I need it to work with Spring Data?
· What else do I need?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have the same schema in all databases, I suggest you check [Spring's Dynamic DataSource Routing](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/). If not, you need to create 4 datasources and 4 entity managers as pointed out by @vlad-mihalcea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each database is going to be represented by a different data source. For every data source you need a different session factory/entity manager factory.

If you want to save in more than one data source in a single transaction you then need XA transactions, therefore a Java EE or a stand-alone transaction manager, like Bitronix or Atomikos.

You have 4 different entity manager factories, you also need specific repositories for each of those:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="your.company.project.repository.access" entity-manager-factory-ref="accessEntityManagerFactory"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="your.company.project.repository.sqlserver" entity-manager-factory-ref="sqlserverEntityManagerFactory"/>
```

Then your application doesn't have to care which repository it uses.

The JpaTransactionManager requires one entityManagerFactory, but since you have 4 you may end up creating for of those, which I think it's undisirable.

It's better to switch to JTA instead:

```
<!-- 1. You define the Bitronix config ->
<bean id="btmConfig" factory-method="getConfiguration" class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices">
    <property name="serverId" value="spring-btm"/>
    <property name="warnAboutZeroResourceTransaction" value="true"/>
    <property name="logPart1Filename" value="${btm.config.logpart1filename}"/>
    <property name="logPart2Filename" value="${btm.config.logpart2filename}"/>
    <property name="journal" value="${btm.config.journal:disk}"/>
</bean>

<!-- 2. You define all your data sources ->
<bean id="dataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource" init-method="init"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="className" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="uniqueName" value="dataSource"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="false"/>
    <property name="driverProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
            <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 3. For each data source you create a new  persistenceUnitManager and you give its own specific persistence.xml ->
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" depends-on="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="dataSourceLookup">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.BeanFactoryDataSourceLookup"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- JpaDialect must be configured for transactionManager to make JPA and JDBC share transactions -->
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

<!-- 4. For each data source you create a new entityManagerFactory ->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

<!-- 5. You have only one JTA transaction manager ->
<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager"
      class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="btmConfig, dataSource"
      destroy-method="shutdown"/>

<!-- 6. You have only one Spring transaction manager abstraction layer ->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

If this proves too much work for your current problem, you can give a try to having 4 JPA transaction managers and see how it works.

Comment: I think that I have everything working except this error "No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined". Can I use the same transaction manager for everything or I have to define one different TM for each data source? That means that I don't need to deal with transactions?

Comment: I had to remove the <props> with the user, password and url because i get this message foreach of the properties: no writeable property url|user|password. After i remove the driverProperties I've got this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: jstels.jdbc.dbf.DBFDriver2 cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource. Maybe the driver is not compatible?

Comment: Most DB drivers have XA support, for that particular one you can roll a LRC Bitronix XA wrapper, allowing you to enlist at most one non-XA data source in a global Tx.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am totally lost. I've already bought a Spring Data Book to try to understand a little more... I don't know what XA is (googled for it already), LRC Bitronix XA Wrapper... :(

Comment: Indeed the learning curve is steep but regard it as a learning experience, you'll have to know all these stuff when doing back-end development anyway.

Comment: If this proves too much work for your current problem, you can give a try to having 4 JPA transaction managers and see how it works.

Comment: The most confusing thing is all those transaction managers. I can't tell the difference between the bitronix transactionManager, jta transaction manager and spring transaction. Spring is the interface and the bitronix the implementation i wonder, but I don't get the need for a JTA Transaction. So, i need, 4 bitrnonix TransactionManager, 4 DataSources, 4 Persistence Unit Managers, 1 JPA Dialect Bean, 4 Entity Manager Factories, 4 Jta Transaction Manager, 4 Spring Transaction Manager Abstraction right? I just keep trying.

Comment: With JTA you need 1 Spring TM and 1 Bitronix TM not 4. You need 4 DS and 4 EMFactories. Spring TM takes care only of transaction boundaries and Bitronix is the XA TM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your schema is same across all the databases, then the best approach is to use hibernate,because hibernate provides portability between multiple databases. once you create the hbm files and pojo classes, the only thing you need to change is the dialect and your datasource.

The transactionmanager support can be provided by spring.